# Using R, how to create a new data set with the Median of a column in my existing dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, data-manipulation, median

I am new to R and I want a new data set from my `dataframe` that will include a new column which represents the `median` of the values in an existing column (called Total Extras) of the `dataframe`. The latter consists of around 5,000 individual observations.
I am a bit confused on how to proceed with this task as the Median need to be calculated based on the following criteria: Property, Month, Year and Market

Currently, my `dataframe` (let's call it mydata1) stands as follows (first 5 rows shown):

```
Property    Date      Month  Year      Market    TotalExtras
ZIL         1-Jan-15    1    2015        UK         450.00
ZIL         1-Jan-15    1    2015        UK         125.00
ZIL         1-Feb-15    2    2015        UK         300.00
ZIL         1-Feb-16    2    2016        FR         225.00
EBA         1-Feb-15    2    2015        UK         150.00
...
```

I need my R codes to create a new `dataframe` (let's call it mydata2) to appear like below:

```
   Property        Date      Month  Year      Market    MedianTotalExtras
     ZIL         1-Jan-15      1    2015        UK         175.00
     ZIL         1-Feb-15      2    2015        UK         250.00
     ZIL         1-Feb-16      2    2016        FR         400.00
     EBA         1-Feb-15      2    2015        UK         328.00
     ...
```

The figures above are for illustration purposes only. Basically, mydata2 is re-grouping the data based on Property, Date and Market with the column 'Median Total Extras' replacing the 'TotalExtras' column of mydata1.

Can this be done with R?

Comment: If your question is *can it be done with R*, than rest assured that it can... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `dplyr` the general gist will be something like:

```
mydata1 %>% 
    group_by(Property, Date, Market) %>% 
    summarise(MedianTotalExtras = median(TotalExtras))
```

where `group_by` arranges the cutting up of the dataset into pieces with unique `Property`, `Date`, `Market` combos, and the `summarise` + `median` calculates the median.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.